# Microservice can not connect to MySQL running in Docker container

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker

I am trying to run my Java microservice locally on MacOs and connect to MySQL db running in Docker container but I get an error:
`java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.`

My docker-compose.yml looks like it:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_v.0.1
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .mysql-dev-env
    ports:
      - 33060:33060
```

However I am able to connect to mysql and create dbs trough docker itself with:

```
docker exec -it mysql_v.0.1
mysql -u root -p
```

Microservice has such application.dev.yml config:

```
db:
  pool.size.maximum: 30
  connection.idle.minimum: 10
  widget:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/dev_widget_platform?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes&autoReconnect=true
    user: root
    password: pass
```

I am trying to connect to db via MySQL Workbench it has no success too.
Seems like I need to apply some network trick but i am new to docker and MySQl.

Comment: can you check if the docker container actually listens on port 33060 on your host, with sth like `netstat -anp | grep 33060` or even `telnet 33060` (but not sure if they work on macos)? you can also check `docker inspect mysql_v.0.1` to see the port mappings of the container, it may help..

Comment: docker inspect mysql_v.0.1 brings  under  "NetworkSettings": 
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null,
                "33060/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "33060"
                    }
                ]
            }

Comment: Your `ports:` forward host port 33060 to container port 33060, but there's nothing listening on that container port; a MySQL container will always listen on the default port 3306.  Try changing `ports: ['33060:3306']` using the standard port as the second port number.

Comment: I changed as you suggested but it still does not work. Now my NetworkSettings: "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "33060"
                    }
                ],
                "33060/tcp": null
            }
Looks like I am doing something wrong or so

Comment: Can you show env_file: .mysql-dev-env, it's seem that you should config: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'. Config to accept connect from remote server/client

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using SSL locally, add this to the end of your connection string

`&useSSL=false`

So it becomes

`url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/dev_widget_platform?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: Tried and it did not help